# サイトからスクレイピングでcsvファイルをダウンロードしたい。

Tags: python, web-scraping

1．以下のサイトから11月7日の野菜価格csvファイルのみをダウンロードしたい。
https://www.seisen.maff.go.jp/seisen/bs04b040md001/BS04B040UC020SC001-Evt001.do

サイト自体は以下のように誰でもデータをダウンロードできる。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

2．以下のエラーが出て、ダウンロードまでに至らない。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上記自己解決

```
elems = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@href]")
```

下記に変更

```
elems = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@href]")
```

再びエラー発生

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

3．以下実行コード

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import urllib.request

try:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get("https://www.seisen.maff.go.jp/seisen/bs04b040md001/BS04B040UC020SC001-Evt001.do")
    
    elems = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@href]")
    print(elems)
    count = 1
    
    for elem in elems:
        download_url = elem.get_attribute("href")
        print(download_url)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(download_url, str(count))
        print("ダウンロード　ファイル数: "+str(count))
        
        time.sleep(3)
        count = count + 1

except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

4. 言語、バージョン
   Python 3.9.12
   selenium 4.6.0

Comment: 該当サイト・ページは登録されたユーザーである必要があるようです。おそらく他の人では有効な情報を取得することは出来ないでしょう。それからエラーメッセージはその2行だけではないはずです。スクリプトのどの行からどのように呼び出されていったか等の情報も表示されているはずですので、略さずにすべてを表示されたまま提示してください。

Comment: こちらのリンクからじゃないと正しくページが表示されませんでした。 https://www.seisen.maff.go.jp/seisen/bs04b040md001/BS04B040UC020SC998-Evt001.do

Comment: エラーメッセージが少ないのは`try except`で`print(ex)`だけにしているからですね。こちらの記事 [\[Python\] 例外処理のやり方と、スタックトレース取得の実装方法](https://www.yoheim.net/blog.php?q=20190601) を参考に`traceback`を使うようにすると通常表示されるような詳細な表示が行われると思われます。それから質問のURLでは質問の`HTTP Error 555: 555`になりましたが、@cubick さんコメントのURLを使うと`urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: javascript>`になりました。その際に質問画面のような都市名・野菜・果実のダウンロード用の表は表示されていませんでした。`urllib.request`ではなく`selenium webdriver`を継続して使って、それらリンクをクリックする必要があるのでは？

Answer (score 2):

ウェブブラウザの Developer Tools を利用すれば判りますが、リンクは JavaScript による form submit になっています(HTTP POST)。それらを考慮すると、以下の様にしてもデータの取得は可能です。

```py
import sys
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

url = 'https://www.seisen.maff.go.jp/seisen/bs04b040md001/BS04B040UC020SC001-Evt001.do'
the_day = '20221107'
r = requests.get(f'{url}?s006.dataDate={the_day}')
r.encoding = r.apparent_encoding
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

tbl = soup.select_one('div.scr1 > table')
if tbl is None:
    print('not found table', file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

# 都市名
cities = [c.text.strip() for c in tbl.select('td:nth-child(2)')[1:]]

# 野菜データ(CSV)
csv_url = 'https://www.seisen.maff.go.jp/seisen/bs04b040md001/BS04B040UC020SC001-Evt005.do'
for i, elm in enumerate(tbl.select('tr td:nth-child(3) a:-soup-contains("CSV")')):
    no = re.search(r",\s*'(.+?)'", elm['href']).group(1)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(f'{csv_url}?s004.chohyoKanriNo={no}', f'{(i+1):02d}_{cities[i]}_{the_day}.csv')
```

**実行後**

```bash
$ ls -1 *.csv
01_主要卸売市場計_20221107.csv
02_仙台市_20221107.csv
03_東京都_20221107.csv
04_横浜市_20221107.csv
05_金沢市_20221107.csv
06_名古屋市_20221107.csv
07_京都市_20221107.csv
08_大阪市_20221107.csv
09_神戸市_20221107.csv
10_広島市_20221107.csv
11_高松市_20221107.csv
12_北九州市_20221107.csv
13_福岡市_20221107.csv
14_沖縄県_20221107.csv
15_札幌市_20221107.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

何故かは不明ですが、質問に記述されたURLだと、Chromeブラウザの手作業ではページが表示されるのですが、当方の環境(Windows10 Python3.11.0)でのseleniumだと表示されない状態ですね。
@cubick さん指摘のURLなら作業が進められたので、以下のようにしてみました。

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import time
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import urllib.request
import traceback #### 詳細な traceback の表示用

try:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    # browser.get("https://www.seisen.maff.go.jp/seisen/bs04b040md001/BS04B040UC020SC001-Evt001.do") #### seleniumだと上手くいかない
    browser.get("https://www.seisen.maff.go.jp/seisen/bs04b040md001/BS04B040UC020SC998-Evt001.do") #### @cubick さん指摘のURL
    
    #### 左上・年月日の並びの一番上をクリック
    browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="s007_Evt001_0"]').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    
    #### 表示された表の項目タイトルを含む行数を取得
    elems = len(browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="content_whitemenu"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr'))
    
    #### 表の項目タイトルを除いた2行目から最後までを繰り返し実行
    for row in range(2,(elems + 1)):
        #### 都市名取得
        cityname = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="content_whitemenu"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[{row}]/td[2]').text
        #### 野菜のCSVダウンロードリンクをクリック
        browser.find_element(By.XPATH, f'//*[@id="content_whitemenu"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[{row}]/td[3]/a[2]').click()
        print(f'ダウンロード：{cityname}')
        time.sleep(3)
    
    browser.quit() #### 終了時 webdriver 停止
except Exception as ex:
    print(traceback.format_exc()) #### 詳細な traceback の表示
```